# Prevent update-grub from scanning ZFS snapshots

Tags: boot, apt, grub2, zfs

Every time there is a new linux-image after `apt upgrade` update-grub runs and scans the entire drive for Linux images. It also scans all ZFS snapshots. After some time it results in huge console output during the upgrade that contains log like:

```
[...]
cannot open 'bpool/BOOT/ubuntu@install': dataset does not exist
Found linux image: vmlinuz-4.15.0-23-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu@install
Found initrd image: initrd.img-4.15.0-23-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu@install
cannot open 'bpool/BOOT/ubuntu@otherSnapshot': dataset does not exist
Found linux image: vmlinuz-4.15.0-23-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu@otherSnapshot
Found initrd image: initrd.img-4.15.0-23-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu@otherSnapshot
cannot open 'bpool/BOOT/ubuntu@anotherSnapshot': dataset does not exist
Found linux image: vmlinuz-4.15.0-23-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu@anotherSnapshot
Found initrd image: initrd.img-4.15.0-23-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu@anotherSnapshot
[...]
```

Is there a way to tell update-grub to skip `.zfs` directory during scans?

Disabling os-prober through `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true` entry in `\etc\default\grub` doesn't work for me. From what I understand os-prober is used to scan all other drives than the bootable one and the ZFS snapshots are on the bootable partition.

Comment: I disable os-prober in grub and then add only the grub boot entries I want in 40_custom. I have many, some obsolete, installs that I do not want in grub menu. I backup and edit my 40_custom with new install, but originally just copied entries from grub menu. `sudo  cp -a /boot/grub/grub.cfg /boot/grub/grub.cfg.backup`

Comment: From my understanding these snapshots allow you to quickly go back to when your system was working if you end up with a boot problem by choosing them from the History in grub.

Comment: Do you happen to have figured this out in the meantime? (edit: for future visitors, [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59787/66736) outlines what @oldfred suggests. And I'm not sure Terrnace's mentioned issue is too bad. because afaik you could still manually edit the grub launch entry to make use of the snapshot when needed

Comment: No, unfortunately not. `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true` doesn't help, probably because ZFS snapshots are on the disk with the system.

Answer (score 3):

I also got annoyed by this a lot. I make snapshots every 5mins, meaning that `update-grub` routinely takes half an hour to finish, needlessly scanning all snapshots.

So I did some digging, adding `set -x` to various scripts executed by `update-grub` and at last could narrow down were this behavior is located (at least on Ubuntu 20.04). Here is how to disable scanning of snapshots:

1. Open file `/etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs` with a text editor
2. Locate the function `bootlist()`.
3. Comment out (prepend with `#`) the following lines (for me they are in lines 543 to 545):

```
        for snapshot_dataset in $(zfs list -H -o name -t snapshot "${dataset}"); do                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            boot_list="${boot_list}$(get_dataset_info ${snapshot_dataset} ${mntdir})\n"
        done
```

4. Profit.

**Edit:** I verified that after this change `update-grub` still adds the desired boot menu entries for installed kernels on my system.

From a cursory investigation, it looks like this code path is only meant to add boot menu entries for kernel images in snapshots (if they contain different ones). If you don't care about those (I don't, for one), this change should be safe.

Comment: Nice. I'm wondering what side effects this change might have?

Comment: Very limited from what I can tell, I augmented my post with my thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from @tlanger's answer. The advantage of this answer is that it should still consider the latest ten snapshots of each dataset. Just not **all you ever made**.

1. `sudo vim /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs`
2. Type `/get information from snapshots of` followed by Enter, to jump to the correct location
3. replace the nested loop with this:

```bsh
    for dataset in $(get_root_datasets); do
        # get information from current root dataset
        boot_list="${boot_list}$(get_dataset_info ${dataset} ${mntdir})\n"

        # get information from snapshots of this root dataset
        # LB: change on 2022-04-25 to speed up update-grub
        ##for snapshot_dataset in $(zfs list -r -H -o name -t snapshot "${dataset}" | grep "${dataset}"@); do
        for snapshot_dataset in $(zfs list -r -H -o name -S creation -t snapshot "${dataset}" | head -n 10 | grep "${dataset}"@); do
            boot_list="${boot_list}$(get_dataset_info ${snapshot_dataset} ${mntdir})\n"
        done
    done
```

4. Adapt as per your usecase the `head -n 10` to whatever number you find reasonable.
5. Change the date in the comment, for your own convenience if this ever breaks.
6. Test it with `update-grub` and notice that it is much faster now.